# Airlow logs are not visible

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-ecs

I have deployed airflow cluster on AWS ECS. Airflow Webserver, Scheduler and worker are running on same host under different containers.

When I try to fetch the logs using Airflow webserver, I am getting below error:

```
*** Log file does not exist: /usr/local/airflow/logs/master_populate_uc_crf_ap/populate_ss_ui_schema__country/2021-03-03T09:54:53.271590+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://ip-10-180-98-37.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8793/log/master_populate/populate_schema/2021-03-03T09:54:53.271590+00:00/1.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. HTTPConnectionPool(host='ip-10-180-98-37.eu-west-1.compute.internal', port=8793): Max retries exceeded with url: /log/master_populate/populate_schema/2021-03-03T09:54:53.271590+00:00/1.log (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f52eae32e10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

If I log in to the the ec2 on which all three(Webserver, scheduler and worker) containers are running, I am able to run below command successfully:

```
curl http://ip-10-180-98-37.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8793/log/master_populate/populate_schema/2021-03-03T09:54:53.271590+00:00/1.log
```

it confirms that logs are getting generated, but Webserver is not able to access the log from worker.

If I logged in into the Webserver docker container and run the same curl command then below error is occurring:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ip-10-180-98-37.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

If I replace the hostname(ip-10-180-98-37.eu-west-1.compute.internal) with localhost then curl will run successfully under Webserver container.
Below are the value of airflow configuration variable:

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__HOSTNAME_CALLABLE: socket:getfqdn
executor = SequentialExecutor
```

Network mode is host.
Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your container is unable to reach the log file. It should have something to do with your network or security group configuration. I would suggest checking these two configurations in your ECS setup.

Cheers :)

Comment: can you mention the configuration

Comment: Geetika - You need to speak/work to the team which provisions your AWS infra they will  have a good idea.. If you are doing it yourself - I suggest goto EC2->Security groups and check your security group setup.

Comment: I am doing it myself...Even if I allow all traffic from anywhere then also I am not able to access. I think some problem is with the host name resolution. ec2 not able to recognize ip-10-180-98-37.eu-west-1.compute.internal. I am still not able to solve this issue. Kindly assist.

Comment: @Geetika were you able to solve your problem?